# Only allow requests with a valid token that's found in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a small app in react where a developer will use my service in their website/app with firebase.

This is how I want it to work

1. The developer who wants to use my service will sign up and retrieve a token on my site.
2. The developer should use this token within their app to request my app (technically the request is comming from an end user which I don't know of, and shouldn't).
3. The security rule will look for this token in the users collection at firestore and only allow the request if an account is found in the collection users.
4. The developer should then only be able to see the posts made used by that token.

How can I achieve this?

Kindly point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Firestore, it's not possible to send extra data along with a query for the purpose of authorization with [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  That's not really secure at all - it would be the same as requiring a plaintext password.

What you will need to do is write some backend code to put the token in the user's [Firebase Auth custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  You can use the contents of custom claims in security rules to securely check if the user should have access to some resources.

For Firestore security rules, you will need to check the contents of [request.auth.token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) in the rule to get the data you put there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for `Custom Claims`. Those are custom values attributes you can attach to the firebase auth user model which then can be loaded inside the firestore rules engine. Get more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims